# swift, objective-c protocol implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

Still trying to get used to swift, but since my obj-c knowledge is close to 0, I have not been able to implement this SocketRocket protocol. Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Here's the obj-c delegate I try to implement**

```
@protocol SRWebSocketDelegate <NSObject>

// message will either be an NSString if the server is using text
// or NSData if the server is using binary.
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message;

@optional

- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket;
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didCloseWithCode:(NSInteger)code reason:(NSString *)reason wasClean:(BOOL)wasClean;

@end
```

**I hoped this was the proper way to implement it; it wasn't...** 
I get *'SocketDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'SRWebSocketDelegate'*

```
class SocketDelegate:UIViewController, SRWebSocketDelegate{
    let socket:SRWebSocket! = SRWebSocket()

    override func loadView() {
        self.socket.delegate = self
    }    

    func didReceiveMessage(message:AnyObject){

    }
}
```

Comment: `func webSocket(webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didReceiveMessage message: AnyObject!)`

Comment: Why are you so good at this and I'm so bad... Seriously though, thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

```
func webSocket(webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didReceiveMessage message: AnyObject!)
```

see

[Functions in Swift Reference Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_240)

Method name in Obj-C `webSocket:didReceiveMessage` is translated such as the first part is the method name, the other parts are the external parameter names (`didReceiveMessage`). Also note that `id` becomes `AnyObject` and Obj-C references are translated with `!` as implicitly unwrapped optionals (this is no longer true, implicitly unwrapped optionals are now rare thanks to attributes added to Obj-C declarations).

Comment: My real problem wasn't the swift (ECMA programmer), it's understanding the obj-c, i really need to get better at it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution: try [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/starscream) - a native Swift Websocket library.