# Use objective c protocols in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

I have some header files declaring my protocols written in objective C, please explain how can I use these methods in swift classes confirming these protocols.

Also as there are no separate header files in swift how can I segregate different protocols in different files.

Please shed some light on this.

Comment: You need to use bridging header. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055198/swift-objective-c-protocol-implementation

Answer (score 1):

Create a Swift bridging header and `#import` your .h files.

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).